# Maven, error copying a file with antrun

Tags: java, linux, maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I have some problems copying files with Maven.

I use the antrun plugin in this manner: (I want to copy the file jdk1.5.0_22.tgz to a temporary folder)

```
<exec executable="cp">
    <arg value="${parent.resources}/jdk1.5.0_22.tgz" />
    <arg value="${iso.tempDir}/"/>
</exec>
```

And it works fine.
Now I make a small change to be independent from the jdk file version: (I only change jdk1.5.0_22.tgz to jdk*.*)

```
<exec executable="cp">
    <arg value="${parent.resources}/jdk*.*" />
    <arg value="${iso.tempDir}/"/>
</exec>
```

In this case I have the following error:
[exec] /bin/cp: impossible to do the stat of '../../resources/jdk*.*': No such file or directory

Why?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? What is the purpose of such copying via Maven?

Comment: I need to create ad iso image containing all the modules of my project plus the jdk needed for the installation of the project itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be a Maven question.

It is even hardly an Ant question.

With `jdk*.*` you are expecting wildcard expansion to be performed by the shell. However, this all is not executed by the shell, rather it is executed by Ant. Ant does not do the wildcard expansion, rather passes the original string including the wildcards into `cp`, which also does not do the wildcard expansion, rather interprets it literally.

As something toward a solution, may I suggest you use Ant's `fileset` to find the file. While you're at it, Ant's `copy` may do the copy, which would then be platform-independent (much nicer than using `cp`).

Comment: I used ant's copy before, unfortunately it doesn't maintains the file permissions in Linux so I has been obliged to change to execute cp.

Comment: That does then not change the fact that you should make Ant iterate over the files (which in fact will be only one), rather than have the wildcards expanded by a shell... that's not there.